# Method extracting feature in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Does visual studio code have features like generating the function, extract method for the C
language? I have seen these features in IntelliJ for Java. But couldn't figure out
in visual studio code for C language

Comment: C does not have the same kind of general code conventions that Java does, except for `main()`, so based on what would VSC generate function skeletons?  C does not have classes (or, therefore, methods), so what might VSC extract functions *from*?

Comment: Is there some standard way to reduce the number of parameters passed in a C function? I notice that sometimes the list of parameters grows unnecessarily. Especially when dealing with multiple arrays, you have to give the array pointer and the size of the array two.

Comment: There's nothing unique to C about parameter lists growing.  The most appropriate solution depends on the circumstances.  Sometimes the function is trying to do too much, in which case you can break it up into multiple functions, each better focused.  Sometimes several pieces of data are closely associated, such that it makes sense to define a structure type to use (among other things) as a function argument, instead of passing all the individual pieces of data separately.  Sometimes, you just need that many arguments.